# angularjs directive for accept input numbers only in the given range

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing web application in angularjs. I have requirement to validate textbox. It should accept only numbers with max 10 digits. I have directive but current directive should not restrict number of digits typed.

```
myapp.directive('validNumber', function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            if (!ngModelCtrl) {
                return;
            }
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (val) {
                if (angular.isUndefined(val)) {
                    var val = '';
                }
                var clean = val.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
                if (val !== clean) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
                    ngModelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return clean;
            });
            element.bind('keypress', function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode === 32) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
       <div class="inputblock" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : ((form1.$submitted && form1.idnumber.$invalid )|| (form1.idnumber.$invalid && form1.idnumber.$dirty))}">
                                <label class="inputblock-label" ng-show="idnumber">{{ 'ID Number' | translate }}</label>
                                <span class="ang-error" style="color:#fff" ng-show="form1.idnumber.$dirty && form1.idnumber.$invalid ">
                                    <span ng-show="form1.idnumber.$invalid && form1.idnumber.$dirty">*{{'Max allowed digits 10' | translate}}</span>
                                </span>

                                <input class="with-icon" type="text" name="idnumber" placeholder="{{ 'ID Number' | translate }}" ng-model="idnumber" required ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,7}$/" > <!--valid-number-->
                            </div>
```

May i know what should be changed in the above directive so that it can accept maximum only 10 digits! Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't use ng-maxlength="10" ?

Comment: Hi Vivz, I can use but my textbox should not accept text.

Comment: Use input type="number" and maxlength="10". No need of directive

Comment: When i change input type to number i can see scroll up and down mark inside the textbox. 'My textbox should be plain.

Comment: Then try with the ng-pattern as ^[0-9]{1,10}

Comment: Hi Viz may i know what should be changed in above regular expression so that it can accept only 10 digits

Comment: Hi OnDoubt. I added ng-patter and ended up with Unexpected next character  at columns 0-0 [^] in expression [^[0-9]{1,10}].

Comment: Hi Viz ng-pattern working fine. But whenever i enter alphabets i want to display enter only numbers. If user tries to enter more than 10 digits then i want to display only 10 digits allowed. Now whenever i enter alphabets also i get Max allowed digits 10 error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code and try. my original purpose of this code was to **limit the number to integer**. But I have modified it a little so you can use this

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module('app').directive('intValidate', intValidate);

function intValidate($locale) {

    var decimalSep = $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.DECIMAL_SEP;
    var toNumberRegex = new RegExp('[^0-9\\' + decimalSep + ']', 'g');



    function toNumber(currencyStr) {
        return parseFloat(currencyStr.toString().replace(toNumberRegex, ''), 10);
    }

    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        require : 'ngModel',
        link : function validate(scope, elem, attrs, modelCtrl) {

            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(newViewValue) {
                var modelValue = toNumber(newViewValue);

                var valid = modelValue <= 9999999999;

                modelCtrl.$setValidity('limitcheck', valid);

                return valid ? newViewValue : undefined;
            });
        }
    };
}

})();
```

and use,

```
<input type="text" id="value" name="value" int-validate>
```

and if you want an error message

```
<p class="help-block" ng-if="cacc.form.value.$error.limitcheck">Max 10 digits allowed</p>
```

Comment: Thanks this works fine. Is it possible to restrict the alphabets in the above directive?

Comment: <span class="ang-error" style="color:#fff" ng-show="form1.idnumber.$dirty && form1.idnumber.$invalid ">
                                        <span ng-show="form1.idnumber.$invalid && form1.idnumber.$dirty">*{{'Max allowed digits 10' | translate}}</span>
                                    </span>

Comment: I am using above code to display error message. If the user enters alphabets i want to show oly numbers are allowed. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: you cant enter alphabets in here.

Comment: Yes but i want to show error message when the user enters alphabets

Comment: Problem with above directive is it accepts 44dddd something like this